# Sorting list items of an unordered list in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, sorting

I got this code to sort an unordered list with regards to their title attribute in place.

```
$('#list li').sort(function(a,b) {
    return $(a).attr('title') < $(b).attr('title');
}).appendTo('#list');
```

It works great on Firefox and IE but it fails on Chrome as soon as the list element count exceeds 10 (see http://jsbin.com/atoput/4)

Is there a better/easier/faster way of sorting the elements on the fly and do you maybe even have an explanation of what Chrome is doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var list  = $('#list');
  var items = list.children('li').get();
  items.sort(function(a, b) {
    var A = a.title;
    var B = b.title;
    return (A < B) ? -1 : (A > B) ? 1 : 0;
  });
  $.each(items, function(idx, itm) { list.append(itm); });
});
```

Preview can be seen [here](http://jsbin.com/atoput/11).

If you want the list to sort based on a descending order, switch around the signs:

```
return (A > B) ? -1 : (A < B) ? 1 : 0;
```

Comment: I don't see how this can work.  `items` is an array which doesn't have a `.appendTo()` method.

Comment: The one thing I'd change is why use the much slower `$(a).attr('title')` when `a.title` works just fine?

Comment: Thanks for fixing.  I mentioned it because it's a pet peeve of mine when people use jQuery for things that it's actually worse at than plain javascript and `.attr()` is one of the most often abused examples.  I see people doing things like `$(this).attr("id")` all the time instead of just `this.id`.  Your version was multiple functions calls and the creation of an object rather than just a single property access.  Maybe the performance isn't consequential most times, but it's a bad habit that will matter sometimes.

Comment: FYI, sorting by `a.title` is ~25 times faster than sorting by `$(a).attr("title")`.  See http://jsperf.com/attr-vs-property-access.

Comment: I accepted the answer. The main reason why the original code didn't work was that returning "titlea < titleb" was not sufficient. It was necessary to return either -1, 1 or 0 depending on the comparison of the title attribute.

Comment: FYI if you replace `$.each` with a for loop you can achieve another boost in performance, since the each call is relatively expensive for larger lists.